# XCode 7: How to find a bug on iPhone when simulator works fine?

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging, crash

I created an ios app, which runs fine on every simulator. With XCode 7 I transfered it to my iPhone 4S. There the Splashscreen is shown and then app is terminated. I don't have any idea why?
How can I find out, what's the problem and where it is?

Comment: Launch the app using the instruments feature and report back (CMD + I, choose sudden termination)

Comment: I started instruments. Then I clicked on run. I see the statistics over the timeline, but nothing happens. Now app is not terminated, but seems to have freezed (it's running for more than 10 min now). Should I have to do something additionally?

Comment: Have you tried adding breakpoints to debug this at all? Put one in your first view controller and see if it makes it that far.

Comment: Now it runs, but only when it is connected with cable to my MacBook. Did I misunderstand, that I can use the app on my iPhone independendly from the debugger? As soon as I disconnect the cable the app terminates.

Comment: The app should still be there on your device after it has successfully run.

Comment: The app is there, but cannot run without being connected. I always used the build-n-run arrow to start it. Do I need a different approach to get it to the device?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88304/discussion-between-switz-and-peter71).